# run java.exe with arguments from powershell

Tags: java, powershell, arguments, wlst

I'm trying to call wlst/jython/python from powershell

set classpath with setWLSEnv.cmd is not set in the right session? so I have tried to set -cp as argument

```
& C:\bea\tpc\weblogic1033\server\bin\setWLSEnv.cmd; 
$cp='C:\bea\tpc\WEBLOG~1\server\lib\weblogic.jar'
$wlst='weblogic.WLST'
$script='C:\domains\tpc\Domain\bin\status.py'
$java="C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JROCKI~1.0\bin\java"
& "$java $cp $wlst $script"
#or
. "`"$java`" -cp `"$cp`" $wlst `"$script`""
#or
& "`"$java`" -cp `"$cp`" $wlst `"$script`""
```

I have tried to quote the command string in various ways without success

The term '"C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JROCKI~1.0\bin\java" -cp "C:\bea\tpc\WEBLOG~1\server\lib\weblogic.jar" weblogic.WLST "C:\domains\tpc\SasTT
pcDomain\bin\status.py"' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:_WORK_\SAS\statusAll.ps1:15 char:2
+ . <<<<  "`"$java`" -cp `"$cp`" $wlst `"$script`""
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ("C:\PROGRA~1\Ja...\bin\status.py":String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the call operator `&`, the next token needs to be the name of a command and nothing else. So instead of this:

```
& "$java $cp $wlst $script"
```

Try this:

```
& $java $cp $wlst $script
```

Sometimes getting arguments to native exes can get ugly.  A technique that usually works but is unsafe if any of your arguments come from user input is this:

```
Invoke-Expression "$java $cp $wlst $script"
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the trouble with how you're formatting your command into a string, `setWLSEnv.cmd` is a script for the Windows Command Prompt. PowerShell cannot execute this file; it does not know how to interpret it, much like how Notepad does not know how to interpret a docx file. Windows associates .cmd files with the command prompt, so your first line is equivalent to

```
& cmd.exe /c C:\bea\tpc\weblogic1033\server\bin\setWLSEnv.cmd
```

(Note that the semicolon is unnecessary since you don't have any other commands on the same line.)

This creates a new process using cmd.exe. This new process executes the batch file, setting the environment variables you expect, and then the process exits, discarding the environment changes.

If you need `setWLSEnv.cmd` to set environment variables prior to executing your program, you should write a batch file that calls it instead of a PowerShell script. Otherwise, you will need to find or write a PowerShell equivalent to set up your environment.

Comment: As I thought. I was was just hoping that there was some magic that could force it to execute in the right session like in unix `. ./env.sh`

Comment: As an alternative, you can use the `Invoke-BatchFile` command in the PowerShell Community Extensions (http://pscx.codeplex.com) that will execute the batch file and propagate environment changes back to the PowerShell process.

Comment: @ReneHH PowerShell does have an equivalent, but it only works for PowerShell files, just like sh-derivatives can only interpret the files written in their dialect. It's not that PowerShell is missing functionality; it's that PowerShell and the Command Prompt are two very, very different types of command line shells. Asking PowerShell to run a .cmd file is kind of like asking an sh-derivative to run a batch file.